# Upload and Download Base64 images from firebase storage in angularfire2: ^5.0.0-rc.2

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic3, firebase-storage, angularfire2

**Here what i have done in my service.ts**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

getRetuarantImageformStorage(res, hotelName) {
  this.storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('Restaurants/' + this.emailToKey(res.email) + '/' + hotelName);
  return this.storageRef.getDownloadURL();
}
```

**This how i called for the method inside my component**

```
this.dataservice.getRetuarantImageformStorage("s@gmail.com", "shangri la");
```

I have manually uploaded the image to the above given path in the firebase storage

**But i have got this error**

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_firebase_app__.storage is not a function
at handleDataService.webpackJsonp.38.handleDataService.getRetuarantImageformStorage (handleData.service.ts:105)
at Restaurants.ts:24
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at SafeSubscriber._next (Restaurants.ts:23)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:238)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:185)
at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:125)
at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:83)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
```

I have searched for a clear documentation for this, but i haven't got any satisfied answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I changed:**
*import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';*

**to:**
*import * as firebase from 'firebase';*